# Need help on laravel resource

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie on Laravel. I was trying to make an API using Laravel Resource.
The Following Code Works well,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class Word extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

But When I try with the following, this doesn't work,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class Word extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'word' => $this->word_name
        ];
    }
}
```

The error shown is,

> Undefined index: word_name

But I have `word_name` column in my table. I would be grateful if anybody help me.

I am using `showapi()` method to load the resource.

```
public function showapi()
{
    WordResource::withoutWrapping();
    return new WordResource(Word::all());
}
```

Comment: You are not using an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, instead you are using a `Http\Resources\Json\Resource`

Comment: How are you calling the Resource, could you post the relevant route?

Comment: @linktoahref Route::get('/getwords','PagesController@showapi');

Comment: Please update your question with `showapi()` method, isn't that's where you are calling Word Resource?

Comment: @fab I think that's okay. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources

Comment: @linktoahref I have updated the question  with showapi() method.

Comment: Your database table must have a column `word_name` in order for that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing a collection to the Resource, you can't directly access the properties of the Modal. Instead for the resource instance you would get a Collection, giving you access to the [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#available-methods). So you could change your resource `toArray()` as

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return $this->pluck('word_name')->keyBy(function ($item) {

        return 'word';

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define variable `word_name` as member of `Word` class.

Comment: I have defined the word_name.